# Images in fotorama look crappy in chrome and edge

Tags: fotorama

the images in fotorama look crappy in chrome and edge on 1x display, but they are ok in FF. I have tried different settings, but the result is all the same.

Here's the preview http://rgbits.com/dev/houseup/test/test.html#7
I have added a plain image below the gallery for comparison.

I can't find any particular reason for this behaviour, please advice.

Comment: I have found a solution:
I removed the following declarations in fotorama.css
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
transform: translateZ(0);
and the image quality improved dramatically.

Comment: looks like this trick doesn't work on all browsers.
Any ideas?